# Using EF Reverse Engineer Code First wizard, getting error after installing Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, code-first

I used the wizard once last week with no problems. Now, after installing Silverlight 5 I get:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude(1024,76) : error CS0433: Compiling transformation: The type 'System.Xml.XmlReader' exists in both 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v5.0\System.Xml.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.XML.dll'

Answer (score 0):

I realize you asked this forever ago but I happened upon a solution that worked for me...

This is actually a bug in the EF Power Tools that they are actively working on ...

If you edit

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Entity Framework Tools\Templates\Includes\EF.Utility.CS.ttinclude

or
EF.Utility.VB.ttinclude if you are using VB

change the assembly lines that include the XML assemblies to explicitly not use the SL libraries then it starts working

so change them to

```
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral"#>
```

Then it should start working